# ActionBar Light, but Holo Dark ActionMode CloseButton

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a `Theme.Holo.Light` style, which is custom designed. Therefore I want to have the little tick on the contextual action mode in normal `Theme.Holo` style.

[image: ActionMode]

As you can see, it would look much better if the tick was white.

I thought the following would work, but no success.

```
<style name="PlayerTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    ...
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@android:style/Widget.ActionButton.CloseMode</item>
</style>
```

Is there some way to make the tick white? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the standard white check mark from the android icon pack into your project as a drawable.  The icon pack can be found here: https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html.  It's under the 01_core_accept folder and named ic_action_accept.png.

Then, set the following property in your style file:

```
<item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_action_accept</item>
```

That should solve your problem.